# Simple Date Formatter parse function error

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I am getting an error when I use SimpleDateFormatter.parse() function. I am making user enter the date and time through DatePicker and TimePicker respectively and I am collecting the information from both the pickers and trying to create a Date object do that I could compare it to another date object (System Date).

But when I am trying to parse the date to form a date format I am getting the error.
[image: Error form Logcat]

The chunk of code causing the error is

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
         int day =  dpicker.getDayOfMonth();
         int month = dpicker.getMonth() + 1;

         if (month < 10)
         {
             monthS = "0" + month;
         }
         else
         {
             monthS = String.valueOf(month);
         }
         int year = dpicker.getYear();

         int minutes = tpicker.getCurrentMinute();
         int hours = tpicker.getCurrentHour();
         if (hours < 10)
         {
             hoursS = "0" + hours;
         }
         else
         {
             hoursS = String.valueOf(hours);
         }


          date = year + "-" + monthS + "-" + day + " " + hoursS + ":" +  minutes  ; 

         tview.setText("Date and Time are" + date) ;


        }
    });

   SimpleDateFormat sdf =   new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:MM");

   try {
     newDate = sdf.parse(date);

} catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
tview2.setText(newDate.toString());
```

I would appreciate any help on this error.

Thanks,
Sid

Comment: You are getting null pointer exception.seems you  did not initialize an object.

Comment: I appreciate your help Tanmay, Could you please explain how can a 'sdf' object can be intialized. I am a begginer at android. Thanks.

Comment: in this line `newDate = sdf.parse(date);` it seems `date ` is not in right format....Print the `date` in console and see the result.

Comment: just print your date variable and check log its coming or not?

Answer (score 0):

You parse `date` outside of onClick listener, so, maybe, at that time variable `date` is not initialized. I think you should move try/catch cycle inside listener.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was actually able to create a date object from year, month, day, hours and time given in DatePicker dialog, this was easier as I bypassed the need to create a String and parse tge string into a date. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `date` is null. The code inside your onClickListener will not execute until the button is pressed.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was actually able to create a date object from year, month, day, hours and time given in DatePicker dialog, this was easier as I bypassed the need to create a String and parse tge string into a date. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not the `sdf` object that is not initialized, this is probably the `data` String that is still null (although we can't be sure until we see the code before it). You try to parse `date`, but from what you posted, you only modify/put value to it in the `OnClickListener` which is not called until the click.

So what you basically do is:

1. declare string date.
2. set onclicklistener.
3. use the string `date` before you initialize it.

Fix it by setting a default value to date or put the parsing in the listener as well (whatever answers the correct logic you need)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was actually able to create a date object from year, month, day, hours and time given in DatePicker dialog, this was easier as I bypassed the need to create a String and parse tge string into a date. Thanks